# How to sync animations on a local player via Photon RPC?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I wanted to sync local animations(UI) via Photon RPC. Is there any way to do that?
I am making a "press meeting button system" just like in among us.
When the player presses the button, it will sync through the network and will show for other players too.(That the button is pressed.)

The meeting button can be used only once by each player.

Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MeetingButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    //~Animator:
    private Animator animator;
    
    //~Bools:
    private bool mouseDown;
    private bool disableMeetingButton;

    //~PhotonView:
    private PhotonView view;

    private void Start()
    {

        mouseDown = false;
        disableMeetingButton = false;
        view = GetComponent<PhotonView>(); // Get the photon component.

    }
    
    private void Update()
    {

        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && disableMeetingButton == false) //Check mouse down for meeting button.
        {

            mouseDown = true;
            disableMeetingButton = true;

        }

        if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {

            mouseDown = false;

        }

    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {

        if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("MeetingButton") && disableMeetingButton == false)
        {

            gameObject.transform.Find("Canvas").transform.Find("MainUIElements").transform.Find("CrosshairHolder").transform.Find("Crosshair").gameObject.SetActive(false);
            gameObject.transform.Find("Canvas").transform.Find("MainUIElements").transform.Find("CrosshairHolder").transform.Find("Hand").gameObject.SetActive(true);

        }


    }

    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {

        if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("MeetingButton"))
        {
            if(mouseDown == true)
            {
                animator = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
                animator.Play("Animation_UI_Panel_MeetingButtonPressed");
                gameObject.GetComponent<SoundHandler>().PlaySFX("MeetingPressed");
                view.RPC("PressedButton" , PhotonTargets.All, 1);
                GameObject.FindWithTag("Spawners").GetComponent<Change_Player_Position>().SpawnPlayers();
            }
        }

    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {

        if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("MeetingButton"))
        {

            gameObject.transform.Find("Canvas").transform.Find("MainUIElements").transform.Find("CrosshairHolder").transform.Find("Crosshair").gameObject.SetActive(true);
            gameObject.transform.Find("Canvas").transform.Find("MainUIElements").transform.Find("CrosshairHolder").transform.Find("Hand").gameObject.SetActive(false);
            
        }
        
    }

    [PunRPC]
    private void PressedButton(int takeMeetingInput)
    {

        if(takeMeetingInput == 1)
        {

            gameObject.GetComponent<SoundHandler>().PlaySFX("MeetingPressed");
            GameObject.FindWithTag("Spawners").GetComponent<Change_Player_Position>().SpawnPlayers();
            animator = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
            animator.Play("Animation_UI_Panel_MeetingButtonPressed");

        }

    }

}
```

[!][It should look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwlpM.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwlpM.jpg)

It works sometimes but not on all players and mostly , it doesn't.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Just a sidenote but why not simply check `if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))` within `OnTriggerStay`?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind game devs, I fixed it using photon raise event see the docs to learn more:)